# Mysql If else in Where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, performance

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1 ="abc" AND field2="xyz"
```

if this query returns me 0 rows then i have to reduce my filter criteria in where clause
like  `SELECT * FROM table WHERE field1 ="abc"` (need to remove one field from Where clause)

this can i handle with case when in where clause i.e

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE CASE WHEN((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE field1 ="abc" AND field2="xyz" )>0)
THEN field1 ="abc" AND field2="xyz"
ELSE field1 ="abc" END
```

BUT I WANT THIS TO DONE WITH IF ELSE STATEMENT(or any other better option instead of case statement)

Comment: 'BUT I WANT THIS TO DONE WITH IF ELSE STATEMENT' - you can't these statements are only available in stored programs in mysql. and even then not in the context of a select

Answer (score 2):

If you are expecting exactly one row, then a simple method is:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE t.field1 = 'abc' 
ORDER BY ( field2 = 'xyz' ) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

If more than one row is possible, then:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE field1 = 'abc' AND
      (field2 = 'xyz' OR
       NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table t2 WHERE t2.field1 = t.field1 AND t2.field2 = 'xyz')
      );
```

Comment: The first one would benefit from `INDEX(field1, field2)`, in that order.